# Financial instrument code crossreference

Tags: finance, codes

Is there some source to have a XREF of various instruments codes as used by different providers ( IE Reuters Bloomberg others ) as well as ISIN, are there some sources/strategies already in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the database at ISIN.com of as part of Refinitiv's reference data (if you were purchasing that).

However, every firm I have worked at generally downloads that data or keeps their own cross-reference table -- since they also included market data codes (*e.g.* RIC, Bloomberg ID, FactSet Exchange Symbol) in the table. Note that the cross-reference has to have a start and end date for these associations since CUSIPs (and hence ISINs) may be reused.